# Unity both duration and cooldown system

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

I have a boss with machine gun and i am trying to make him shoot for 5 seconds and then stop for 5 seconds and so on. I tried to create an IEnumerator and call it on Start (as far as i know i can not call it from update) but its not the behaviour i want as i always want him to start shooting when he spots the player. Any help is appreciated.

```
IEnumerator MachineGunShootTimer()
{
    while(true)
    {
        machineGunOnCooldown = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

        machineGunOnCooldown = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
public float firingSeconds;
public float cooldownSeconds;

float _fireSecondsRemaining;
float _cooldownSecondsRemaining;

void Start() {
    _fireSecondsRemining = firingSeconds;
    _cooldownSecondsRemaining = cooldownSeconds;
}

void Update() {
    if(_cooldownSecondsRemaining > 0) {
        _cooldownSecondsRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
    } else {
        _fireSecondsRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
        Fire();

        if(_fireSecondsRemaining <= 0) {
            _cooldownSecondsRemaining = cooldownSeconds;
            _fireSecondsRemaining = firingSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed, thanks a lot for fast reply.