# I'm trying to add gun shooting and cooldown into my 2d game

Tags: unity, c#

the problem i'm having with projectile is that it spawns on my cursor instead of my gunEnd, it also spawns with no force at all. I'm also having a problem implimenting a cooldown, I'm new to C# so this doesn't come naturally.
this is the code for my gun.

As I said, I need help with both the projectile and the cooldown, Thanks.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class shootBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float shootCooldown;
    public float force;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject gunEnd;
    private Vector3 aim;
    private bool canShoot;
    private float gunCooldown;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        //Shoot
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        aim = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.nearClipPlane));
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && canShoot)
        {
            gunCooldown = Time.time + shootCooldown;
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, aim, Quaternion.identity);
            Rigidbody b = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            b.AddRelativeForce(transform.forward*force);
            canShoot = false;
        }
        if (!canShoot && Time.time > gunCooldown)
            {
                canShoot = true;
            }
        if (gunCooldown < 0)
        {

        }    
    }
}
```

Edit:
I should add that this is my 1st ever project in C# except the basic stuff you do to learn the basics.
Edit 2:
My scripting seems to be fixed now, ill share the code i ended up with for my gun and bullet
Gun Code

```
public class shootBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float shootCooldown;
    public float force;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public GameObject gunEnd;
    private Vector3 aim;
    private bool canShoot;
    private float gunCooldown;
    public long damage;
    public float lifeCycleEditor;
    public bool positive;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        positive = true;
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        //Shoot
        Camera cam = Camera.main;
        aim = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.nearClipPlane));
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0) && canShoot)
        {
            gunCooldown = Time.time + shootCooldown;
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);
            bulletProperties.lifeCycle = lifeCycleEditor;
            bullet.AddComponent<bulletProperties>();
            bullet.transform.position = gunEnd.transform.position;
            var direction = aim - gunEnd.transform.position;
            Rigidbody b = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            b.AddRelativeForce(direction*force);
            canShoot = false;
        }
        if (!canShoot && Time.time > gunCooldown)
            {
                canShoot = true;
            } 
    }
}
```

Script referenced in the code above in bullet.AddComponent.

```
public class bulletProperties : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float lifeCycle;
    private float lifeCycleRemaining;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        lifeCycleRemaining = lifeCycle;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        lifeCycleRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (lifeCycleRemaining <=0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As for the cooldown, take a look at this https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/182238/unity-both-duration-and-cooldown-system

Comment: Youdo not need to add the bulletComponent each time when you instantiate your Bullet. Rather add that script to your bullet prefab and each time you create a new one with Instantiate, it will have already your script on it. Think of prefabs as templates.

Comment: A solution to your problem should be posted as an Answer below the Question, *never* edited into the Question post itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

> 

```
Object.Instantiate

Declaration
public static Object Instantiate(Object original);
Declaration
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);
Declaration
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent, bool instantiateInWorldSpace);
Declaration
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
Declaration
public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
```

The second parameter is *position* rather than *direction*.

It might be code like:

> 

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab); //just create a GameObject instance
bullet.transform.position = gunEnd.transform.position; //set position
var direction = aim - gunEnd.transform.position; //get shoot direction
Rigidbody b = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
b.AddRelativeForce(direction*force);
```

hope it helps :)

-----------Edit:

An example of destroying the bullet:

> 

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float lifeTimeMax;
    private float lifeTimeRemaining;

    void Start() {
        lifeTimeRemaining = lifeTimeMax;
    }

    void Update() {
        lifeTimeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (lifeTimeRemaining <= 0){
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

You can add it to your bulletPrefab  :)

Comment: ill try this later on when i got a little time, thanks for your input <3

Comment: hello, I Added your suggestion into my code and it worked, the problem im having now is the objects go away as soon as they hit the cursor location(i need a variable bullet time) and also the bullet is never deleted.

Comment: considering each bullet has a separate life cycle, you can add a new script to bulletPrefab. Set a maximum alive time and count it down in Update().  Destroy it when time's up. Using Time.deltaTime you will get *The interval in seconds from the last frame to the current one*

Comment: i have no clue how i'd implement that to be honest, as i said im really new to C# and am a little out of my comfort zone, sorry for noob questions.

Comment: I've submit an edit to show the example.No offense but you might follow the tutorial first :<https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingSection.html> :-)

Comment: Non taken, thanks you've been a huge help, all i got left to do with my weapon is to fix it disappearing at my mouse and add collision, i gotta code my enemies before i do collision though. Thanks again :)

Comment: i should add, the way i fixed my bullet was i made a script with your code and now when im duping the bullet im adding the script to the duped bullet, i was having an issue with the base bullet destroying its self to begin with. I'll edit my post to show the method of which i fixed it.